# Переписать запросы из sqlite to my sql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

1. insert into users (userId,data,UserName) values (" + chat_id + ",datetime('now','localtime'),'" + name + "')

2.update  users set data =datetime('now','localtime') where userId=" + chat_id + "

3.SELECT CAST((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s',users.data))/(60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT) || ' д ' ||
         CAST(((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s',users.data)) % (60 * 60 * 24))/(60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ' ч ' || 
  CAST((((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s',users.data)) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60))/60 AS TEXT) || ' м ' 
     from users where userId= " + chat_id + "

работаю с склайтом,понадобиилось срочно переписать три запроса и возник заковык с тремя запросами
также заковык и с localtime?в my sql нет такой функции?

Comment: я не вижу тут функции localtime(), я вижу тут строковый параметр к функции datetime. Судя по всему он просто сообщает этой функции что требуется локальное время. `datetime('now','localtime')` в MySQL заменяется настоящей функцией `now()`. Аналоги для остальных вызовов ищите в документации http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html

Comment: В sqlite нет типа datetime. Поэтому там даты/время хранятся как строки или числа. А для работы с ними используются [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). В mysql типы datetime есть. Соответственно, там можно делать все совсем по другому. Осталось узнать структуру таблиц sqlite и mysql, чтобы хоть что-то посоветовать.

Comment: MIKE,функция now() дает мне не локальное время,а GMT.

Comment: александр структура таблиц самая простая-id,name,userId,date.все что нужно это записывать время локальное ,обновлять его по запросу и вычитать значение текущего времени и записаного в бд.что как раз делает запрос под номером 3.я так понял в MY sql это будут пляски с бубном,так как локальное время записать возможности нет,запрос под номером 3 так же не осуществить видимо

Comment: `date` какого типа? В sqlite, понятно, что строка. А в mysql? Тоже простая строка или `datetime`? И, кстати, в запросах есть `data`, но не `date`.

Comment: date типа datetime ,в запросах data это название столбца в котором находится дата .мне нужно взять дату из таблицы,вычислить разницу между этой датой и текущей и вывести все это пользователю в формате 00 д 00ч 00 м